# Vaadin 23 + spring-boot 3.0.2 application not launching

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

We have a vaadin application on version 23 which was using spring-boot version 2.7.3.
We have some old library high vulnerabilities reported by static scan. so to fix that we tried to use the spring-boot version 3.0.2 with the same application. the application build successfully and also it shows that the application started on port xxxx but the application is not launching and also there are no errors on the console. It just shows the following message:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Feb 02 16:32:45 CET 2023
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> No message available

Is it possible to use spring-boot 3.0.2 with vaadin 23?

the application should be accessible on localhost.

Comment: What error do you get on the server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use Vaadin 23 with Spring Boot 3.

Spring Boot 3 support comes with Vaadin 24. The most recent version is 24.0.0.alpha9.

Make sure you add the pre-release repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

    <!-- Main Maven repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <url>
            https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
        </url>
    </repository>
    <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
    <repository>
        <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <url>
            https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
        </url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried with the vaadin 24 prerelease  and getting this error [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project rmod-tools: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/dev/work/P00156-BDS-RMOD-Tools/app/src/main/java/com/ing/bds/views/search/SearchView.java:[311,17] cannot access com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate
[ERROR]   class file for com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate not found

Comment: Polymer templates are deprecated with Vaadin 24. Do you try to migrate an existing app?

Comment: Hi, yes, migrated the polymer templates to lit template and it worked.